# i want to save my Html table data in mysql table in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new on php i need to save me html table data to my data base i don't know how to start it .. i have html table and database table created....
can any body help me how it will done.

My Table Is

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>00125</td>
        <td>20012</td>
        <td>454545</td>
        <td>45454</td>
        <td>45454</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ash</td>
        <td>dsd</td>
        <td>dfd</td>
        <td>adsfd</td>
        <td>adfdsf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/5.html

Comment: @Khushboo your comment is unrelated to question and also you are suggesting to use deprecated function of mysql_* api which makes no sense ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Time to study.**

1. PHP With PDO (here you can work with databases using PHP): http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php
2. Use a POST form to save the data. You need to put each td value inside of a input. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html
3. You need to create a database (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) and a table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).
4. And finally insert command, to add the values inside a row of the table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

**You can run each command using PDO or shell command, as Terminal or even CMD.**

If you are using a server that don't have mysql, don't forget to install (or a local machine): http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/